# How to auto expand matrix in power BI while displaying it on LCD screen

Tags: matrix, powerbi, fullscreen

I am working on `Power BI`. I have created a pie chart and a matrix. After that, I connect my laptop to an LCD screen. In the focus mode of the pie chart, it is displaying all over the screen on LCD i.e. the width/height is auto-adjusted. But for matrix, it is not adjusting to the screen, i.e. the matrix display is small and almost unreadable. How can I adjust the matrix to be shown on the LCD screen in full?

**Matrix**

[image]

**Pie Chart**

[image]

As you can see that the pie chart is occupying almost all the space on the screen. While matrix is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most useful settings for screen resolutions are the page size of the report page  and the text size options of the matrix view. You may need to prepare two pages for two screens with different resolutions.

[image: PowerBI Page size]
[image]

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69299604/6854117) related to power-bi?