# Power Bi Calculate Growth Over Last Month and Show it in a Matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, percentage, powerbi-desktop

I have a below matrix. I want to calculate the `% Growth over month` and to show in a matrix

[image: Sample Screenshot of Matrix visual]

**Fields**

[image: Fields used in Maatrix]

**Expected Output**

| Company | August | September | GOLM % | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EBS-EASEBUSINESS SOLUTIONS | 5940 | 0 | -100% | 5940 |
| SWEETREAT CAFE | 5940 | 0 | -100% | 5940 |
| M/S SPORTS ONE PHARMACY | 1188 |  | -100% | 1188 |

**Tried Solution**

I have tried this [Solution](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-Growth-in-a-Matrix-adding-a-column/m-p/833789#M400450). But it's not working for me

```
GOLM = 
VAR SelectedMonth =
SELECTEDVALUE (
   Dates[Month],
     MONTH ( TODAY () )
 )

 VAR PrevMonth =
  SELECTEDVALUE (
   'Source Data'[Month Updates],
     MONTH ( TODAY () )
  ) - 1

  VAR Growth =
   CALCULATE(
   DIVIDE(
    SelectedMonth - PrevMonth,
    PrevMonth,
    0
    )
    )

    RETURN
    IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Source Data'[Month Updates]) = PrevMonth,
    SUM('Source Data'[SALES VALUE]),
    IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Source Data'[Month Updates]) = SelectedMonth,
    SUM('Source Data'[SALES VALUE]),
    FORMAT(Growth, "Percent")

     )
     )
```

**Error**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**DAX File**

Here is my [Dax](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5p4UP3lOex9V2doBkBUf6ITMkC9gMrH/view?usp=sharing) File

Comment: Can you properly load dax data to the table ?

Comment: @MrRobot I have added it you can check it now

Comment: @MrRobot any update brother ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this;

First create a DAX table by using modelling pane;

```
Growth = 
VAR CurrentMonth = FORMAT(TODAY(), "MMMM")
VAR PrevMonth =  FORMAT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1), "MMMM")
VAR tmp1 = SELECTCOLUMNS('Source Data',
                "SV_PrevMonth", CALCULATE(
                                    SUM('Source Data'[SALES VALUE]), 
                                    'Source Data'[Month Updates]=PrevMonth), 
                "SV_CurrentMonth", CALCULATE(
                                    SUM('Source Data'[SALES VALUE]), 
                                    'Source Data'[Month Updates]=CurrentMonth), 
                "PN", 'Source Data'[ProductNameFull],
                "CN", 'Source Data'[CustomerNameFull],
                "CP", 'Source Data'[Company]
            )  
return tmp1
```

Then add a measure to your table

```
GrowthPercentage = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM(Growth[SV_CurrentMonth]) - SUM(Growth[SV_PrevMonth]), SUM(Growth[SV_PrevMonth]),0))*100
```

The result wil be like;

[image]

Comment: can we change `SV_PrevMonth` to `August` and `SV_CurrentMonth` to `September` and vice versa?

Comment: Secondly can we do this  without making a  new table ?

Comment: You can add as much as columns to the table for previous months, but with Dax, this is what I can think of. Maybe another solution can be done in advanced editor...

Comment: Ok. One thing more I  want to tell you that the count of the previous month is not accurate.

Comment: There are some filters on your report, and obviously they are not applied to the new table. Please remove those filters (or apply them to the new table) and check again.

Comment: can you please confirm for me what you put in columns and values? It would be great if you share me the `.dax` file

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a measure in the Source Data Table itself like below:

```
GLM =
VAR Curr_Month =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Source Data'[SALES VALUE] ),
        'Source Data'[Month Updates] = FORMAT ( EOMONTH ( TODAY (), 0 ), "mmmm" )
    )
VAR Prev_Month =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Source Data'[SALES VALUE] ),
        'Source Data'[Month Updates] = FORMAT ( EOMONTH ( TODAY (), -1 ), "mmmm" )
    )
VAR GROWTH = ( Curr_Month - Prev_Month ) / Prev_Month
RETURN
    GROWTH
```

and of course, you need to change the format of the measure to PERCENTAGE.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I think its working fine, but I couldn't verify 100% since the pbix file doesn't have current month data - October

Comment: You can do `-1` for current month which will give you `september` and `-2` for `august`

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. And it looked fine for me. Check it out. There are few NAN error which probably can be addressed using IFERROR

Comment: have you made any changes to the formula? Above formula only refers to one column!!

Comment: This works fine but not in matrix

Comment: If you mean that you're getting a separate column of %GOLM for each month, that's expected because that's how matrix visual is designed. If you'd like to have a separate column for GOLM you'll need to create a separate table with the required columns.